# Java REST service answer takes too much time

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jax-rs, export-to-csv

This is a problem i've been trying to deal with for almost a week without finding a real solution , here's the problem .

On my Angular client's side I have a button to generate a CSV file which works this way :

1. User clicks a button.
2. A POST request is sent to a REST JAX-RS webservice.
3. Webservice launches a database query and returns a JSON with  all the lines needed to the client.
4. The AngularJS client receives a JSON processes it and generates the CSV.

All good here when there's a low volume of data to return , problems start when I have to return big amounts of data .Starting from 2000 lines I fell like the JBOSS server starts to struggle to send the data like i've reached a certain limit in data capacities (my eclipse where the server is running becomes very slow until the end of the data transmission ) 
The thing is that after testing i've found out it's not the Database query or the formating of the data that takes time but rather the sending of the data (3000 lines that are 2 MB in size take around 1 minute to reach the client) even though on my developper setup both the ANGULAR client And the JBOSS server are running on the same machine .
This is my Server side code :

```
@POST
@GZIP
@Path("/{id_user}/transactionsCsv")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Transactions de l'utilisateur connecté sous forme CSV", response = TransactionDTO.class, responseContainer = "List")
@RolesAllowed(value = SecurityRoles.PORTAIL_ACTIVITE_RUBRIQUE)

public Response getOperationsCsv(@PathParam("id_user") long id_user, 
                                 @Context HttpServletRequest request, 
                                 @Context HttpServletResponse response, 
                                 final TransactionFiltreDTO filtre) throws IOException {    
    final UtilisateurSession utilisateur = (UtilisateurSession) request.getSession().getAttribute(UtilisateurSession.SESSION_CLE);
    if (!utilisateur.getId().equals(id_user)) {
        return genererReponse(new ResultDTO(Status.UNAUTHORIZED, null, null));
    } 
    //database query 
    transactionDAO.getTransactionsDetailLimite(utilisateur.getId(), filtre);
    //database query 
    List<Transaction> resultat = detailTransactionDAO.getTransactionsByUtilisateurId(utilisateur.getId(), filtre);
    // To format the list to the export format 
    List<TransactionDTO> liste = Lists.transform(resultat, TransactionDTO.transactionToDTO);
    return Response.ok(liste).build();      
}
```

Do you guys have any idea about what is causing this problem or know another way to do things that might not cause this problem ? I would be grateful .
thank you :)

Here's the link for the JBOSS thread Dump :
http://freetexthost.com/y4kpwbdp1x

Comment: It can indeed be the payload (2MB data transfer). You can try to gzip encode your content before sending it from server along with content-encoding header.

Comment: Already tried that , data from 2 Mb went to 80 Kbytes but still as slow as without compression

Comment: Are you sure that problem is on server side? Did you measure timings with e.g. curl, to ensure that JavaScript processing of server response is not the problem? Why does your server produce JSON when the endpoint is named transactionsCsv? Where is the CSV being generated?

Comment: Have you profiled it on the server side?  Have you profiled it on the client side?  Do you know which part of the processing takes the largest proportion of the time?

Comment: Actually i've put a console.log in the client to notify me when it starts receiving data from server and noticed that once it receives the data (JSON format) it generates the CSV very quicly .Ive measured the time also that takes the webservice to process data and it takes just 10 seconds while the client starts receiveing data 1 minute after  therefore i'm 99% sure that it's "the sending the data part" that causes the problem . the CSV is being generated in the client side.

Comment: Well, still the response data has been parsed and converted into a JavaScript object then. You should really also add some JavaScript fragments and mark where request starts and ends, and what the timings are.

Answer (score 0):

I've found in other contexts (using RMI) that the more local you are, the less worth it compression is.  Your machine is probably losing most of its time on the processing work that compression and decompression require.  The larger the amount of data, the greater the losses here.

Unless you really need to send this as one list, you might consider sending lists of entries.  Requesting them page-wise to reduce the amount of data sent with one response.  Even if you really need a single list on the client-side, you could assemble it after transport.

Comment: That's one of the solutions i've been thinking about , sending a chunked response to the client .I tired to do that but no clue on how to make it work in my case with my service , do you have any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: The stateless approach is to make the page (page #, and page size) part of your request as a query parameter.  Then use those parameters to return the so specified part of the list.  The drawback to this approach is that if your data changes between requests you could lose an entry or double it.

There's also a stateful approach: create a resource for your search result with a POST function, and keep the search result around until it is released with a DELETE (or you expire it).  Then page on that.  This way your search result doesn't change while you're mid-traversal.

Answer (score 0):

To measure performance, we need to check the complete trace.

Many ways to do it, one of the way I find it easier.

1. Compress the output to ZIP, this reduces the data transfer over the network.
2. Index the column in Database, so that the query execution time decreases.
3. Check the processing time between several modules if any between different layers of code (REST -> Service -> DAO -> DB and vice versa)
4. If there wouldnt be much changes in the database, then you can introduce secondary caching mechanism and lower the cache eviction time or prefer the cache eviction policy as per your requirement.

To find the exact reason:

Collect the thread dump from a single run of the process.From that thread dump, we can check the exact time consumption of layers and pinpoint the problem.

Hope that helps !

[EDIT]

You should analyse the stack trace in dump and not the one added in the link.

If the larger portion of data is not able to process by the request,

1. Pagination, page size with number of pages might help(Only in case of non CSV file)
2. Limit, number of lines that can be processed.
3. Additional Query criteria like dates, users etc.

Sample REST URL :

```
http://localhost:8080/App/{id_user}/transactionCSV?limit=1000

http://localhost:8080/App/{id_user}/transactionCSV?fromDate=2011-08-01&toDate=2016-08-01

http://localhost:8080/App/{id_user}/transactionCSV?user=Admin
```

Comment: Should i generate a thread dump of the local JBOSS process (where my app is running) while executing the service ?

Comment: Yes, you can use JVisualVM or such tools to check the process runinng

Comment: I just added the link for the thread dump generated with JVisualVM

Comment: Sorry Vinay I didn't get it , there are many threads which one should I analyse ? (i'm pretty new to java)

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced that the problem comes from the server trying to send big amount of data at once . Is there a way i can send the http answer in several small chunks instead of a single big one ?